# why cant I change colnames with dates?

Tags: r

I have created a dataframe with columns representing Lon position, Lat position and beyond the 3rd column its dates. however I'm unable to rename the columns with the date values.

```
rtime<-as.Date(time,origin='1900-12-31')
```

which gives the desired output as date with dd-mm-yyyy format.
Here is my attempt to rename the columns:

```
colnames(dfR)[3:368]<-rtime
```

I'm unable to change the names using this. any input?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Does `colnames(dfR)[3:368]<-as.character(rtime)` work for you? If not, have you checked that `length(rtime)` is 366, and does not contain any `NA` values? i.e. `any(is.na(rtime))` should be `FALSE`

Comment: Oh this worked perfectly fine. thankyou so much. for my analysis till now I just changed the names var in raster istelf but the output was not desirable eg:x2020.01.01.